# How to save an image in a folder?

Tags: php

This is my code to save an external image on the server. It does work.

```
$imgfromurl = file_get_contents('http://www.lavanguardia.com/r/GODO/LV/p4/WebSite/2017/03/07/Recortada/img_lbernaus_20170307-110204_imagenes_lv_terceros_istock-578792430-kUN-U42609284081yLC-992x558@LaVanguardia-Web.jpg');

$im = imagecreatefromstring($imgfromurl);

$width = imagesx($im);

$height = imagesy($im);

$newwidth = $width/2;

$newheight = $height /2;

$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);

imagecopyresized($thumb, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

$newsimgpath = uniqid().'.jpg';
$imgjpeg = imagejpeg($thumb, $newsimgpath); //save image as jpg

imagedestroy($thumb); 

imagedestroy($im);
```

But if I want to save the image in a folder, it doesn't work anymore.

I have tryed to change this:

```
$imgjpeg = imagejpeg($thumb, $newsimgpath);
```

to this

```
imagejpeg($thumb, '/imgnews/'.$newsimgpath);
```

or to this:

```
imagejpeg($thumb, realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).'/imgnews/'.$newsimgpath);
```

but the image is not saved in that folder ( that has permissions 777 ).

**Why ?**

EDIT:

error_log:

```
[10-Mar-2017 08:52:32 America/New_York] PHP Warning:  imagejpeg(/home/xxx/public_html/imgnews/58c2afa0c2c4b.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/xxx/public_html/ad.php on line 14
```

Comment: What about taking a look into your http servers error log file?

Comment: Any error log? Have you tried searching the image file through the file system, in case it's been saved in a wrong folder?

Comment: `to this` can not work because of starting `/` dont thing that `/imgnews` is root folder on your system. And after that you dont need the `realpath()` call. You should print the created filename to debug it better

Comment: @arkascha just added error_log above

Comment: Ok, so we can assume you are a step further, right?

Comment: @arkascha ehm no

Comment: Well, that warning reads interesting, doesn't it? In general `'/imgnews/` as folder does not make any sense since it is an absolute path. I seriously doubt you have a folder of that name in your file systems root. `dirname(__FILE__)).'/imgnews/` might make sense, but we cannot say, only you can take a look at your file system. Why I don't understand is why you don't use a _relative_ path or define an absolute base folder in an explicit manner.

Comment: @arkascha this is my file system: http://i.imgur.com/MoKGyF6.png and the ad.php script is in the public_html folder :)

Comment: So you do indeed have your answer. The warning says exactly what the issue is, doesn't it?

Comment: @arkascha yes thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as seen in the error - you haven't that directory.

as seen in your image - https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLRf9.png you have newsimg directory.

you have 2 options:

- create directory imgnews
- in your code change imgnews to newsimg